Standardizes regression coefficients in R
This is the formula for BETA (standardizes regression ceofficients):
\begin{align}
\text{BETA}_2 & = \frac{r_{y2}-r_{23}r_{y3}}{(1-R_{2.3}^2)}
\end{align}
mtcars |>
  select(hp, drat, wt) |>
  cor()

When I take this correlation coefficients und calculate BETA_hp_wt in R:
BETA_hp_wt <- (.66 - (-.45 * -.71))/(1 - -.45^2)

BETA_hp_wt # BETA_hp_wt = 0.28

The Value is much lower and so total different to fitting lm.beta:
fit <- lm(wt ~ hp + drat, data = mtcars) 

fit_s <- lm.beta::lm.beta(fit)

summary(fit_s) # BETA_hp_wt = 0.42

Why?!

Your formula is for a partial correlation coefficient, not a standardized coefficient!

The Formula of the partial correlation is: $r_{Y2 \cdot 3} = \frac{r_{Y2} - r_{Y3} \cdot r_{23}}{\sqrt{(1 - r_{Y3}^2)(1 - r_{23}^2)}}$
I think, "my" formula for the standardized regression coefficient is correct. You can find it for instance: www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats1/x92.pdf.

Thank you: before the formula was formatted I misread it.  I suspect your question might be answered in the lm.beta vignette at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lm.beta/vignettes/comparison.pdf .

OK, my stupid mistake:
The formula for BETA_hp_wt was simply wrong, because the square didn't include the minus. The correct formula is:
BETA_hp_wt <- (.66 - (-.45 * -.71))/(1 - (-.45)^2) # .42

Sorry.
